# How to Create MDI Child forms asynchronously?

Tags: vb.net

I have Parent VB.Net form that has to create some MDI childs.

Each MDI has to connect to a database to do some staff which may take some time...

I'm trying to create the MDI child asynchronously using the following code but it stills execute synchronously :

```
ParentForm.BeginInvoke(Sub() 
                       CreateMDIChildForm()
                       End sub)
```

This code executes but it's still synchronous, and the parent form freezes.

I tried to create the MDI in a separate thread but then I can't join the form created to the parent form.

Does anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing in the load event?  That part is still in the UI thread...

Comment: The MDI childs are generated dynamically. So, the code connects to the database first, creates the controls separately, create the MDI Form, adds the controls to the form and then displays the MDI form

Comment: So, the longest job is not done in Load event of the form but before creating the form

Comment: You will have to profile the parts to see what section of code is taking the longest.  `BeginInvoke` puts the routine in the UI thread since the `ParentForm` is on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
Dim Thread as new Thread(sub()
                               ParentForm.BeginInvoke(sub()
                                                      CreateMDIChild()
                                                      end sub)
                         end sub)
Thread.Start()
```

With this, the MDI child form is still created by the parent form but everything is done in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this with the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Open(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() Me.CreateMDIChildForm())
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateMDIChildForm()
        Dim f As New Form2()
        MsgBox("OK")
    End Sub

    Public Class Form2
        Inherits Form
        Sub New()
            Thread.Sleep(5000)
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

And the fix would be something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Open(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (Me.operationCompleted Is Nothing) Then
            Me.operationCompleted = New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf Me.CreateMDIChildFormCompleted)
        End If
        Me.asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(Nothing)
        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf Me.CreateMDIChildForm)
        thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateMDIChildForm()
        Dim f As New Form2()
        Me.asyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted(Me.operationCompleted, f)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateMDIChildFormCompleted(args As Object)
        Dim f As Form = DirectCast(args, Form)
        'TODO: Set mdi child, show window etc.
        MsgBox("OK")
    End Sub

    Private asyncOperation As AsyncOperation
    Private operationCompleted As SendOrPostCallback

    Public Class Form2
        Inherits Form
        Sub New()
            Thread.Sleep(5000)
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method to fix issues like this is *not* to try to load forms in separate threads, but, rather, to do only the time-consuming work in a separate thread.

In this circumstance, what that means is that you would load the MDI child forms normally, all on the same UI thread, but inside the child forms, they would each start a separate thread to perform the DB-related work which is causing the hangups.  That way, the DB stuff won't cause the form-loading to hang up.  The form will load and show itself quickly and then the database work will be done after the form is already visible.

You may need to disable some, or all, of your controls on the child form until the DB work is complete.  You may also want the child form to display some sort of spinning animation to show that it is still loading.  The easiest way to implement separate threads in your UI, for things like this, is to use a `BackgroundWorker` component.  You will find it in the Components section of your form designer tool box.